# Sunshine - Udacity! List Not Being Displayed with dummy data( AS 1.2.1.1)

Tags: listview, android-studio

Fragment contains a list view that is not being displayed and there are no compile errors.
List needs to be displayed in the app for the dummy data mentioned in MainActivityFragmant.class . As of now code compiles without any errors but dummy data is not being displyed.

This is the MainActivity.java

```html
package com.example.fewryee.sunshine;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is the MainActivityFragmant.class.

```html
package com.example.fewryee.sunshine;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        String[] forecastArray = {
                "Today - sunny - 76/89",
                "Today - sunny - 76/89",
                "Today - sunny - 76/89",
                "Today - sunny - 76/89",
                "Today - sunny - 76/89",
                "Today - sunny - 76/89",
                "Today - sunny - 76/89",
        };
        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));
        ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item_forecast,R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,weekForecast);
        ListView listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure that this part of code which creates the fragment is in activity_main.xml file

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.sevak1994.sunshine.MainActivityFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```